# Need help build a dynamic query with Between dates in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have UI where a user can search on optional parameters.I am writing a SP and as a testing database I am using AdventureWorks.

For some reasons I dont seem to find a way how to include

Where ModifiedDate  between ''' + @Fromdate + ''' And '''+ @ToDate + '''')

in my existing SP.Can you help?

My sp looks like this

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE SearchPerson_Dynamic
(
@FirstName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@LastName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@EmailAddress NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@Phone NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@FromDate DATETIME =NULL,
@ToDate DATETIME =NULL

AS
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @Where NVARCHAR(1000) = ''
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * FROM [Person].[Contact]'

IF @FirstName is not null
SET @Where = @Where + 'AND FirstName = @_FirstName '
IF @LastName is not null
SET @Where = @Where + 'AND LastName = @_LastName '
IF @EmailAddress IS NOT NULL
SET @Where = @Where + 'AND EmailAddress = @_EmailAddress '
IF @Phone IS NOT NULL
SET @Where = @Where + 'AND Phone = @_Phone '

-- NEED TO INTEGRATE A SEARCH BETWEEN @FromDate and @ToDate 

IF LEN(@Where) > 0
SET @sSQL = @sSQL + 'WHERE ' + RIGHT(@Where, LEN(@Where)-3)

 EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL,
    N'@_FirstName VARCHAR(50), 
            @_LastName VARCHAR(50), 
            @_EmailAddress VARCHAR(50), 
            @_Phone NVARCHAR(25)',  
    @_FirstName = @FirstName, 
            @_LastName = @LastName, 
            @_EmailAddress = EmailAddress,
            @_Phone = @Phone
            MISSING @FROMDate and @ToDate  --HOW DO i DO IT HERE
```

One thing I have not done is that some fields EG Surname the user can select "ALL" in the UI from the drop down. How would I implement a search where I dont have an exact parameter?

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Always worth reading Erland Sommarskog's articles on dynamic search, if you haven't before: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html. Also, what problem are you encountering with adding the @FromDate and @ToDate to the search?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it Correct to do If @FromDate is not null and @ToDate is not null     Set where =@where  + 'ModifiedDate' between ''' + @Fromdate + ''' And '''+ @ToDate + '''')

Also in the executeSql do I simply add @_FromDate=@FromDate,@_ToDate =@ToDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I was to rewrite your stored proc, I would do the following

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SearchPerson_Dynamic
(
@FirstName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@LastName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@EmailAddress NVARCHAR(50) = NULL, 
@Phone NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
@FromDate DATETIME =NULL,
@ToDate DATETIME =NULL
)
as
begin

    SELECT * FROM [Person].[Contact]
    where
        FirstName = coalesce(@FirstName, FirstName) and
        LastName = coalesce(@LastName, LastName) and
        EmailAddress = coalesce(@EmailAddress, EmailAddress) and
        Phone = coalesce(@Phone, Phone) and
        ModifiedDate >= coalesce(@FromDate, FromDate) and
        ModifiedDate <= coalesce(@ToDate, ToDate)
end
```

This is better as its not executing text for the stored procedure and could be optimized.

If you want to use the dynamic sql, you could cast the date to a normal string, ie

```
IF @FromDate IS NOT NULL AND @ToDate IS NOT NULL
    SET @Where = @Where + 'AND ModifiedDate between ''' + cast( @FromDate as varchar(50) ) +  ''' and  ''' +  cast( @ToDate as varchar(50) ) +  ''' '
```

Comment: Such query will most likely do table scan.

Comment: Quite true, unless you put in `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. FYI, there a real good article on this at http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: are you saying if you put Option(recompile) it will not do a table scan?

Comment: @user231465 - when specifying the option (recompile), the compiler will see

Comment: didnt finish my comment : @user231465 - when specifying the option (recompile), the compiler will see the fields your using cause it gets compiled each time its run and then use the proper indexes.